# Is Parse `objectSaveInBackground`, An All Or Nothing Save

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I need to save two arrays to a parse object. One that contains the person `objectId` and the other contains comments.

```
 postObject[@"ids"] = newIds;
 postObject[@"comments"] = newComments;
 [postObject saveInBackground];
```

Now if one saves without the other, it will screw up my app. In my `cellForRow` method, i expect them to be the same in length.

Will `postObject` only save if both arrays succeed in saving, or is it possible that there can be a partial save.

Comment: It's possible in some scenarios. But not a simple one like yours. You can validate against a successful block like the one provided below. The only thing you should be concerned with is reachability or network connection processing this request. But there are simple checks for that. And just in case you can use `saveEventually` in the callback as an extra precaution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience I have never seen only part of an object be saved. However you if you use a completion block you can write something to check that the object was saved correctly.

See example from parse docs:

```
[postObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (succeeded) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}];
```